# Table with 3 foreign keys, mapping in JPA

Tags: mysql, jpa

I have to map `UserPresentation`, now I feel like this is a ManyToMany, but it has 3 foreign keys which it uses (2 point to resemble the `PlanningPresentation` and 1 for User).

I am really doubting if I should give `PlanningPresentation` an id but I am not really sure, if it would need an id.

I am using hibernate to persist everything to Java classes.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDbjz.jpg) is my database scheme:
[image: Database scheme]

Comment: Definitely give it an autogenerated ID, as for all the other entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer that you should give `PlanningPresentation` an `id`. Also, table `UserPresentation` should have id of table `PlanningPresentation` as a reference key, in place of `presentation_id` & `planning_id`.